# Understanding the map function when the first argument uses flip

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am learning about higher-order functions from 'Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!' by Miran Lipovaca. I know that the flip function takes a function and returns a function like the original, but with the first two arguments flipped.

I don't fully understand how the following example with the map function works.

```
ghci> map (flip subtract 20) [1,2,3,4]
[19,18,17,16]
```

Map takes a function and applies it to each element of the list, resulting in a new list. But since flip is the function map takes, with parameters `subtract 20 [1,2,3,4]`, would the resulting function be `20 subtract [1,2,3,4]`?

I don't think this is correct since a value such as 19 is only produced if you type `subtract 1 20`. I am not sure how subtract would work in the above example to produce the output list.

Comment: Basically `flip` is sometimes unnecessary if you could use an infix notation of a function. Such as `\`subtract\` 20`. So you may do `map  (\`subtract\` 20) [1,2,3,4]`. Or better `map ((-) 20) [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: The parentheses are important – you can't "decompose" `(flip subtract 20)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, here the function [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) takes is `(flip subtract 20)`, this is the parameter you pass to `map`. So that means that:

```
map (flip subtract 20) [1,2,3,4]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[flip subtract 20 1, flip subtract 20 2, flip subtract 20 3, flip subtract 20 4]
```

[**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) is a function that takes a function and flips the parameters. So `flip subtract 20` is semantically equivalent to `\x -> subtract x 20`. Our list is thus equivalent to:

```
[subtract 1 20, subtract 2 20, subtract 3 20, subtract 4 20]
```

[**`subtract :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:subtract) is the "flipped" version of `(-)`, so it is equivalent to:

```
[20 - 1, 20 - 2, 20 - 3, 20 - 4]
```

and thus equivalent to:

```
Prelude> map (flip subtract 20) [1,2,3,4]
[19,18,17,16]
```

A shorter version of the above expression is thus:

```
map (20 -) [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 3):

`flip` has the following functionality: it applies a given function on the two given parameters in reverse order ("flipped").

```
Prelude> :t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

That's how `(flip subtract 20)` becomes the function f(x) = 20-x, where `(subtract 20)` corresponded to g(x) = x-20.

Then, f is applied to each list item using the map function.

Answer (score 3):

> But since flip is the function map takes...

No. `map` takes the function as its first parameter - which here is `flip subtract 20`. This is indeed a function, as we'll now see (if it wasn't, the compiler would raise an error because it's expecting a function here).

We'll start with [subtract](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:subtract) - which is actually defined as `flip (-)`. This means `flip subtract` is simply `(-)`, or:

```
flip subtract = \a b -> a - b
```

as opposed to

```
subtract = \a b -> b - a
```

So, by currying:

```
flip subtract a = \b -> a - b
```

and substituting in 20:

```
flip subtract 20 = \b -> 20 - b
```

So `flip subtract 20` is indeed a function, which returns the result of subtracting its argument from 20. `map`ping this function over the list given gives the result shown.